# Same height images inside Cards in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to have a list of Material UI  components that would have images of the same height. However, the height of some images are lower (and the width of some is too large).

How can I make their height responsive and the same for all cards?
Thanks!

[image: Cards of Material UI]

css

```
.card {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}

.card > button > img {
    height: auto;
}
```

.tsx file

```
import{ useContext} from "react";
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import './Catalog.css';
import { MoviesContext } from "../../services/context";

const NavLink = require("react-router-dom").NavLink;

const MovieCards = () =>  {
  const { movies } = useContext(MoviesContext);  
  
  return (
    <div >
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
      {movies.map((movie) => (
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={2} key={movie.id}>
          <NavLink to={"movie/" + movie.id}>
            <Card className="card">
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  alt={"Poster of " + movie.title}
                  className="BeerListItem-img"
                  image={movie.picture}
                  title={movie.title}
                />
              </CardActionArea>
              <CardActions>
                <Button size="small" color="primary">
                  <FavoriteBorderIcon />
                </Button>
                <Button size="small" color="primary">
                  {movie.rating}
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </NavLink>
        </Grid>
      ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieCards;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the image a fixed height and width:

```
.card > button > .jss103{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: It does not work.. in case Another solution of setting`.card { height: 90% }` partially works - it does not work when scaling down..

Comment: The selector is wrong, you need to change it to .card > button > .jss103, because the component is not using img tag, it's using div with class jss103.